# Plot colour change!

Tags: plotting

I am trying to change the colour of the 2 curves on this contour plot. I am not very familiar with Mathematica yet, so any help is appreciated. This is the copy and pasted code and the picture is below.

```
ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[{\[CapitalDelta]\[Lambda]1minus2e  == \[Lambda]2e - \[Lambda]1 + \[Omega]Capitale (t[\[Theta]2e ] - t[\[Theta]1]), 

 CosDegree[\[Theta]2e - \[Theta]1] == SinDegree[\[Phi]2] SinDegree[\[Phi]1] +  CosDegree[\[Phi]2] CosDegree[\[Phi]1] CosDegree[\[CapitalDelta]\[Lambda]1minus2e ] }],

   {\[CapitalDelta]\[Lambda]1minus2e, 0, 60 }  , {\[Theta]2e, 0, 60 }, 

 Prolog -> {Black, PointSize[Large], Point[{31.948028324349036`,51.7127788640602`}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual code (InputForm) rather than just an image of the code.

Comment: Please share write or copy-paste your code in the appropriate format. Screenshots won't get you much help here.

Comment: Maybe add option like `ContourStyle -> {Red, Green}`  after `Prolog`?

Comment: You have not included the definitions required to evaluate your code.

Comment: SinDegree and CosDegree are not *Mathematica* functions.

Comment: This site expects runnable code.